# Can survey monkey handle a websites "forms"?

Tags: surveymonkey

The API makes it sound like survey monkey is only good if I'm making an app.

My usecase is that I have a research project and I want to just shoot participants over to fill out a form, then use a webhook to know when they complete it.  Like on my end I know my UserId, so I want to send user X to survey monkey to a SPECIFIC form, then when they complete it, I would like to know so I can log a complete entry in my DB.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Sounds like you want to create a private app (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/build-a-private-app/). In regards to the UserId tracking, use survey custom variables if you are using weblink collectors, or recipient custom fields if you are using email collectors.